# Karate UI Testing - Stop closing browser after each scenario

Tags: automated-tests, ui-automation, karate

I have a case, suppose there are 5 validations in the first scenario and if 2nd validation fails then the remaining 3 validations are skipped.

In order to avoid this, I want to put each validation in a different Scenario so that all validations are verified. But I have observed that after each scenario the browser is getting closed.

Is there any way by which I can keep the browser instance open after the Scenario executes?

> My verifications are 1st verification checks all buttons and 2nd
> checks all links on the page. In case if any of the buttons are not
> matching then the link verification is skipped.

```
* match actualButton contains only expectedButton
* match actualLink contains only expectedLink
```

Comment: In 1 step I'm verifying all buttons on the page and in step 2 I'm verifying all the links of that page. This cannot be done through parallel programming as I'm passing my expected links and button through a json file. Below is the verification code.

* match actualButton contains only expectedButton
* match actualLink contains only expectedLink

Please let me know a way I can do this type of verification through passing it in Examples for Scenario Outline.

Comment: I think karate is the wrong tool for you and you don't seem to read any of the links. please consider what you are asking for as not supported and look for another tool

Comment: I got a solution for my problem. Found a code that continues execution after 1 verification is failing. Below is the code that helps.

* configure continueOnStepFailure = { enabled: true, continueAfter: false, keywords: ['match'] }

Comment: @Peter Thomas : Can you please remove the duplicate mark that you have added to this question and mark this question as active. I will mark it answered.